# Xamarin Forms bind a command in a custom controler with Prism

Tags: c#, button, xamarin.forms, command

I'm facing an issue and I can't figure it out. I have a custom control, to simplify it let's say I have a button inside of a frame inside of a frame. I want the command of the button to be bindable and the button is private. So, here is my code :

**CustomControl.cs :**

```
public System.Windows.Input.ICommand CommandInButton
{
    get { return ButtonInFrame.Command; }
    set { ButtonInFrame.Command = value; }
}

public static readonly BindableProperty CommandInButtonProperty = 
    BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName:"CommandInButton",
        returnType: typeof(System.Windows.Input.ICommand),
        declaringType: typeof(CustomControl),
        defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

private Button ButtonInFrame;
```

**Myview.xaml :**

```
<local:FrameButtonImage Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                                ColorInButton="LightBlue"
                                SourceImageInButton="male.png"
                                IsSelected="{Binding IsMenSelected}"
                                CommandInButton="{Binding SelectMenCommand}"
                                />
```

**MyViewModel.cs : (I'm using Prism)**

public DelegateCommand SelectMenCommand { get; private set; }

```
public MainPageViewModel()
{
    SelectMenCommand = new DelegateCommand(SelectMen, CanSelectMen);
}
    private void SelectMen()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Hello men");
}

private bool CanSelectMen()
{
    return !IsMenSelected;
}
```

**My problem : it's never trigger SelectMen().**

If I bind the command in a simple button like that :

```
<Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3"
                Text=">"
                FontSize="Large"
                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                Command="{Binding SelectMenCommand}"/>
```

It's work like a charm ! So I supposed I do mess in the CustomControl.cs... Maybe someone can help me ? Thanks !

Comment: Hey Nicolas, you're using ICommand to declare your CommandInButton and finally using DelegateCommand when trying to implement it. I think that could be the issue.

Comment: Hi ! 
DelegateCommand is an ICommand, so it's not the problem :/

Comment: Some time ago I added something similar to the flex button control, maybe cross check that code to look for differences https://github.com/robinmanuelthiel/flexbutton/blob/master/Flex/Controls/FlexButton.xaml.cs

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround but I'm sure it's possible to do better. I set my command to be a property of my custom control and add a method to set it to be the command of the button when the command is set.

**CustomControl.cs :**

```
public System.Windows.Input.ICommand CommandInButton
{
    get; set;
}

public static readonly BindableProperty CommandInButtonProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "CommandInButton",
        returnType: typeof(System.Windows.Input.ICommand),
        declaringType: typeof(CustomControl),
        defaultValue: null,
        propertyChanged: CommandInButtonPropertyChanged);

private static void CommandInButtonPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var control = (CustomControl)bindable;
    control.ButtonInFrame.Command = (System.Windows.Input.ICommand)newValue;
}
```